# Boostrap select : class selectpicker doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-select

I send a ajax request to have the different option for my select tag.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/first_line_benefits',
    data: { tablename: tablename },
    success: function(data) {
        var dataArray = data[0];
        var ret = "";
        for (var j = 1; j < dataArray.length; j++) {
            ret += "<div class=\"filter_button col-md-4\">";
            ret += "<select class=\"selectpicker\" multiple><option value='0' selected>Nothing selected</option>";
                for (var i = 0; i < dataArray[j].length; i++)
                {
                    ret += "<option>"+ dataArray[j][i] + "</option>";
                }
                ret += "</select></div>";
            }
            $('#filter').html(ret);
        }
    });
```

The problem is : nothing appears on the page.
But if I remove the selectpicker class, a basic multiple select appears.

I tried to instance the selectpicker on the JS

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

And I tried to show the selectpicker with the method "show"

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('show');
```

**EDIT :**

[Screenshot of the homepage (selectpicker class is here but nothing appears on the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfJpp.png)

[Browser console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqRnT.png)

Comment: did you include plugin for `selectpicker`? Any console errors??

Comment: Yes I include the CDN on my header file. Any console errors.. :/

Comment: Do you have any console errors logged in browser console?

Comment: I have not console error in the browser console

Comment: I added two pictures to show you my browser console and my homepage with the class "selectpicker"